# MACRO VBA - "run time error '1004' application - defined or object defined error"

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop

Hi can anyone figure out why I am getting this message..

> run time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Here is my code, the problem line seems to be:

`range("A1").Select`

here is the rest of the code:

```
Sub HorizontalLoop()
Dim lCol As Long

Sheets("output").Select

For lCol = 1 To 100
    Dim inputrange As String
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(lCol).Value) Then
           inputrange = Cells(1, lCol).Value
           ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("input").Select
           range("A1").Select
           ActiveSheet.Paste
           Sheets("output").Select

        End If

Next lCol
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I notice that in `range("A1").Select` `range` is not with a capital, meaning that VB did not parse it as the `Range` method. Possibly you have to prepend the object of which you want to get a range, e.g. `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select`.

Comment: At the very top (before `Sub HorizontalLoop()`), put `Option Explicit` to make sure your variables are okay.  I think you have a variable called `range` somewhere.  Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: for your information, no cells are in active in your code to select the entire column

Comment: would the active cell not be the cell its currently looping through? sorry if is a daft question @karthick

Comment: pls see the answer below i have given

Comment: yes, range has no capital R which is strange, ill try that @PaulOgilvie thanks

Comment: @MacroMan ill try explain as best as I can.. i want to loop through the A row and i want to skip the cell is there is no value, but when there is a value i want to copy
the values in the corresponding column and save them to another worksheet to the range stated in the active cells value.    sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BruceWayne that is all my code :)

Comment: Question for those saying the "R" isn't capitalized - VBA should capitalize it automatically, if it reads it correctly as a `Range`. Since it's not capitalizing, I don't know if it's reading the `Range` correctly...

Comment: @BruceWayne the code is working now, however range is still not capitalized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Cell A13 is Active cell in worksheet output, see the below code

```
worksheets("output").Range("A13").Activate
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Copy Worksheets("input").Range("A1")
```

it will copy the entire column and paste it to the worksheet input

Comment: you were right there was no active cel, ive replaced acticecell with     `Cells(1, lCol).EntireColumn.Select` and its worked :) thanks

Comment: @HushHoney, please mark as this is solution for your question

Comment: @HushHoney - While this certainly works, it still leaves your macro using `.Select`, which isn't best practice.  Read through [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) as using `.Select` can cause many headaches, especially as you bounce between worksheets/workbooks, which was some of the problem here.

Comment: I wonder If you can help me with something else, in my code I am selecting the entire column, how would I select all the column from row 4 and down?

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks, will look into it, you all have been so helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify the `Range("A1")` with the the worksheet name (as mentioned in Paul Ogilvie's comment.

But you don't need to switch back and forth between the worksheets to paste. After the "copy" you can just add the "Destination".

I did a cut down version of your code (just 2 columns) so you can see what I mean:

```
Sub HorizontalLoop2()

Dim lCol As Long
Dim inputrange As String
Dim wsO As Worksheet
Dim wsI As Worksheet

Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output")
Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input")

For lCol = 1 To 2

If Not IsEmpty(wsO.Cells(lCol).Value) Then
inputrange = wsO.Cells(lCol).Value

wsO.Columns(lCol).Copy _
Destination:=wsI.Cells(1, lCol)

End If

Next lCol

End Sub
```

This assumes of course that you want to paste to the same column number!